# SWR hook error: "An argument for 'Fetcher' was not provided"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

It's my first time using SWR hook, and everything is working great actually. But I have an error and I really don't know what is going there, so let me show you my code first.

This is global configuration

```
<AuthContext>
    {isValidRoute && <Navbar />}
    <SWRConfig
        value={{
          fetcher: (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)
        }}
    >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SWRConfig>
</AuthContext>
```

And this is where I'm using it

```js
import useSWR from "swr";

import { NavbarPart3 } from "../NavbarStyled";
import { dataObject } from "../../../GlobalInterfaces/AuthContextInterfaces";

const Part3 = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const userId: dataObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Auth"));
    const { data } = useSWR(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/user/singleU/" + userId.user.id
    );
    console.log(data);
  }

  return <NavbarPart3></NavbarPart3>;
};

export default Part3;
```

Now, this is the **ERROR**

```
Expected 4 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
use-swr.d.ts(4, 91): An argument for 'Fetcher' was not provided
```

**The Goal**: I just want to get rid of that problem. Do you know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Where have you written SWRConfig? in _app.tsx/document.tsx

Comment: _app.tsx specifically

Comment: I have done the exact same configuration as the docs do and some courses do as well, but that error keeps showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The `SWRConfig` provider where you define the global `fetcher` needs to wrap the component where `useSWR` is called.

---

I'm assuming you're calling the `Part3` component somewhere within your `NavBar` component, which would explain the error you're seeing.

You have to move `{isValidRoute && <Navbar />}` inside the `SWRConfig` provider.

```js
<AuthContext>
    <SWRConfig
        value={{
            fetcher: (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)
        }}
    >
        {isValidRoute && <Navbar />}
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SWRConfig>
</AuthContext>
```

---

As a side note, do not conditionally call `useSWR` (which is a custom React hook) as that will break the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

In your `Part3` component, move the `useSWR` call to the top-level of your component and the `localStorage` call inside a `useEffect`.

```js
const Part3 = () => {
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState()
    const { data } = useSWR(
        // Using the arrow function syntax so that the request is only made when `userId.user.id` is valid
        () => "http://localhost:5000/api/user/singleU/" + userId.user.id
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const auth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Auth"));
        setUserId(auth);
    }, []);

    console.log(data);

    return <NavbarPart3></NavbarPart3>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer, everything makes sense actually, but, after the changes an re-starting the app, the error didn't dissappear

Expected 4 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
use-swr.d.ts(4, 91): An argument for 'Fetcher' was not provided

Comment: Where are you using `Part3`?

Comment: Part3 it's part of my Navbar

Comment: My navbar has 3 parts, and i'm using the SWR in part1 and part3, when i made the changes the error looked like it was gone, but cameback immediately, and i tried to use the useEffect hook to get the localStorage information, but, when the useSWR try to fetch, gave me id of undefined, because i think it's executing faster than the useEffect so there's no data to pass as props in the SWR hook

Comment: The change around the `localStorage` shouldn't affect the error you're seeing though. As long as `SWRConfig` is wrapping all the components that use `useSWR` there should be no error happening. Just as a test, if you provide the `fetcher` directly in both your `useSWR` calls, does the error go away?

Comment: ``````Expected 4 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
use-swr.d.ts(4, 98): An argument for '' was not provided.``````

Lack 2 arguments, at least the error changed

Comment: I changed the code , like this

``````
const { data }: multipleUsers = useSWR(
    "http://localhost:5000/api/user/allU/" + userId.user.id,
    fetcher,'',data
  );
``````

Now this is the problem `````` const data: user[]
Block-scoped variable 'data' used before its declaration.ts(2448)
Part1.tsx(44, 11): 'data' is declared here.``````

Comment: Make sure to pass the argument as `() => "http://localhost:5000/api/user/singleU/" + userId.user.id` (with the arrow function), otherwise you'll get that error.

Comment: Damn, that was crazy but i think there are no errors now, thanks man i'll figure out the res t !

Comment: Yo, actually, the only small error i'm having is this one 

``````
Block-scoped variable 'data' used before its declaration.ts(2448)
Part3.tsx(46, 11): 'data' is declared here
``````

What can be causing this problem ? It's because of the last argument, i put data there

Comment: Try using a different variable name. Feel free to create a new question for the issue you're having though.